# Unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-emulator

I have an AVD (platform version `4.2.2`) running on emulator which actually shows up if I type `adb devices` in the terminal window.

When I try to run "Device Screenshot" in `uiautmatorviewer`, I got an error saying "Unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly". I'm stuck trying to have `uiautomatorviewer` recognise my emulator.

Here is the screenshot showing details of AVD if that helps:

[image: AVD properties screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the adb.exe file was somehow missing from the android -> tools folder.So I copied it to that and now it's working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open uiautomator.bat file in notepad. and find below line

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs% -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir= -jar %jarpath% %*
```

and change it to

```
call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=C:\DEV\androidSDK\tools" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing this issue.
check if platform-tools folder is present inside android sdk folder.
There must be platform-tools and tools folder.
if not present copy and paste platform-tools folder inside sdk folder

Comment: Yes. This worked for me . If there is no directory "platform-tools" inside sdk , create one.
And then copy adb [From /usr/bin/adb or anyother] and keep it inside "platform-tools"